# Server name is not showing in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 while connecting

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed 'SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe' and 'SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x86-ENU.exe' but while connecting to the database it is not showing the server name, instead it showing '(local)' but not connecting when i click on connect button it is giving an error i.e., "login properties are not properly set" and i am using "windows authentication" mode, visual studio 2010 professional is already installed and it is working fine.

Comment: You need to replace (local) with the name of the server that you're trying to connect to. Is the server on your computer or is it on a different computer?

Comment: server is on my computer itself

Comment: Then (local) is correct and your error is to do with something else. Please edit your question and put in the exact error that you see. Did you install the SQL Server? (not just SSMS, SQL Server). Can you see SQL Server in your list of windows services?